# How to add text after a forward slash

Tags: symbols

I want to write this; `/camera/image_raw`, but it seems impossible to compile. The forward slash is not the issue, but as soon as I put text behind it doesn't work :(

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I expect the issue is the underscore character which indicates a subscript and can only be used in math mode. I suggest you use `/camera/image\_raw` instead. If that doesn't work you need to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: `_` is a special character: it is used in math formulae to denote a subscript. Write: `/camera/image\_raw` or \verb+/camera/image_raw+ (in the latter case it will be typeset with a teletype font).

Comment: @Nicola Talbot: Outpaced while I was checking my comment. As usual, forgot to check that point myself.

Answer (score 11):

The underscore `_` is a [special character](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/symbols.html) that TeX interprets as an instruction. (In this case, it's a subscript instruction for use in math mode.) To actually make an underscore symbol appear you need to use `\_` (or `\textunderscore`). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

/camera/image\_raw

\end{document}
```

Or as Bernard mentioned, you can also use the `\verb` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\verb+/camera/image_raw+

\end{document}
```

However, be careful with `\verb` as you can't use it in the argument of a command. (See [Why doesn’t verbatim work within …?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin).)

If your text represents a path (which it seems to) you can also use the `\path` command provided by the [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\path{/camera/image_raw}

\end{document}
```